# Give help or provide assistance

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am not sure which one is correct to use to describe the verb of "given" or "providing" help to someone.

I am trying to say that my professor helped (e.g., with reference letters, research opportunities, etc) me and still willing to help in the current time and in the future. On other words, she is someone that I can always count on her and I am thankful for her help.  So, can I say:

> For many times, you have always **provided your assistance to me**.

OR:

> For many times, you have always **given me your help**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Providing assistance" is not technically incorrect, but is not something that people actually say to each other. "I'm very grateful for all the times that you helped me in the past" would be how I would phrase this idea. This way, it's somewhat formal because you're speaking to your professor, but it's closer to everyday speech.

Comment: I'm guessing this might be an excerpt from a thank-you letter, so it may not be everyday speech. That said, I still agree with your guidance here.